# How to run multiple commands in a single package.json line with configuration

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, package.json, universal

I want to run the to build commands (clienr and server) in one npm run commands.
So on my package.json scripts section I added this line:

```
"build-all": "ng build --prod && ng run web-app:server",
```

The problem occurs when I run this commands: npm run build-all --configuration=qa.europe.

The configuration is loaded when I run each commands separately but not when I run the above commands.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get any errors when running `npm run build-all`?

Comment: please add package.json content so we can see the scripts

Comment: I am not getting any errors but the configuration is not applird

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start:production": "npm install && npm run build && npm run start:prod",
    "start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

npm run start:production it will run "start:production" & "start:prod" both scripts

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use postinstall, it will look as next:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ng run web-app:server",
    "postinstall": "ng build --prod --configuration=qa.europe",
}
```

So after npm install, the build of your UI starts. And after that will start your server.

Comment: But I am changing the configuration per environment. I cant hard code it in the package.json